# Skipping payment and shipping method not working in magento with cache enabled

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout

I have successfully skipped the payment and shipping method steps in magento checkout page, by manually calling the savePaymentAction and saveShippingAction in SaveBillingAction. Since im having only one shipping method(free shipping) and only one payment method(paypal) active. I set them manually all the time. This method works great until i keep the cache management disabled. Once i enable the cache, the review page displays the payment method and there is no continue button or no proceed checkout. When i disable the cache, again everything starts working fine. But i need my site to work with cache enabled, please help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks in Advance.